# How to make files and folders more secure?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to make files and folders more secure. So no hacker can access not even folder structure should be expose and PHP Security Scanners should give much efficient report ?

I just scan my website which is in CodeIgniter. I've got terrible report. Folder structure and their contents are totally exposed even sessions Ids too.

What should I do to prevent this ? can .htaccess to every folder prevent this ?

I used "Acunetix WVS Reporter".

Comment: First thing to realise is that it is *impossible* to achieve your goal of securing your site "so no hacker can access".  You need to develop a threat model of the types of cracker you want to resist, including their capabilities and resources.  Only then you can adopt relevant measures; [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) will be a better place to ask than SO.

Comment: I expect you're on shared hosting, which isn't as secure as having your own (virtual or dedicated) server. I'd recommend trying a VPS, as they're _so_ cheap now (a few US dollars a month to start with) that there aren't many reasons not to. Also, move your files/folders outside of your `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Can you hyperlink to the report in question (removing any site-identifying info, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't place anything, that should not be public accessable, into a public accessable folder (`httpdocs/`, `public/`, or whatever the documentroot is)

Answer (score 0):

For my site, when i want to include javascript, CSS or images (anything external, really),

i have a PHP file which gets the file contents, like so:

```
<?php
 $explode = explode(".", $_GET[f]);
 $md5 = md5($explode[0]);
 echo file_get_contents("secretfolder/$md5.$explode[1]");
?>
```

And in usage in HTML

```
<img src='include.php?f=heart.jpg'>
<style type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='include.php?f=styles.css'>
```

Then put an index.php in that folder, which redirects to your homepage or displays a phony 404 error.

You should debug and expand the PHP, to remove potential code injection or XSS exploits. I suggest Seeing [File GET contents](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

For more information

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be for CodeIgniter
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Better_Server_Setup_for_CI